# C same address with different pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, int, dereference

```
int *ptr = calloc(10,(sizeof(int)));
int *ptr2 = (ptr);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    int r = rand() % 20000;
    *(ptr + i) = r;
    printf("[i:%d, v:%d, a:%p]", i, *(ptr + i), ptr+i);
    fflush(stdout);
}
printf("\n");
printf("[v:%d, a:%p]", *(ptr2), ptr2);
printf("\n");

*ptr2=5;
printf("[v:%d, a:%p]", *(ptr2), ptr2);
printf("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("[i:%d, v:%d, a:%p]", i, *(ptr + i), ptr+i);
}
printf("\n");

free(ptr2);
free(ptr);
```

And here is the output:

```
[i:0, v:5933, a:0x600010360][i:1, ...

[v:5933, a:0x600010360]
[v:5, a:0x600010360]

[i:0, v:5, a:0x600010360][i:1, ...
```

Please explain why there are two different values for the same address? - This actually doesn't happen..

And also Freeing pointers the way I did gives error:

*** glibc detected *** /home/travis/build/batousik/Practical-C2/bin/.libs/lt-practical_trees: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000e05010 ***

In actual program I have test data in int array, and Tree data type. I populate Tree with some data from the array, then I am trying to recursively free every value of the node and node in the tree and that fails. Is it because all the value pointers in the nodes are actually one memory chunk? should i then do something like memcopy of a value from the array into newly allocated memory space for the node value?

Comment: The value is different because you explicitly change it every time before printing.

Comment: @inspiredI am sorry for this question had an all nighter with c, inded code does change the value everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you are freeing the same pointer twice. You point to the address returned by `calloc()`<sup>1</sup> in the following line

   ```
   ptr = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
   ```

   and then you make `ptr2` point to the same place with

   ```
   ptr2 = ptr;
   ```

   so freeing either of `ptr` or `ptr2` actually free's the same pointer.
2. There is nothing suggesting that the value at a given address has actually two values, it's just that

   ```
   *ptr2 = 5;
   ```

   changes the value of the first element pointed to by `ptr` or `ptr2`, and you in fact always overwrite the value at that address before printing.

If you do this right before the problematic `free()` calls in your code

```
fprintf(stderr, "value of ptr : %p\n", ptr);
fprintf(stderr, "value of ptr2: %p\n", ptr2);
```

the same value will be printed, so you actually need **a single** call to `free()` passing any of `ptr` or `ptr2` but not the other one after the one was passed.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You don't need to use `calloc()` if you are going to explicitly initialize the data right after the `calloc()` call. And also, you should check that `calloc()`/`malloc()` didn't return `NULL`.</sub>

Comment: And what about two different values for the same address?

Comment: @Batousik I don't see that happening in your output at all.

Comment: "...right before the `free()` calls..." - that in itself is a problem, as they both hold the same address. There should be *one* call to `free()`

Comment: @iharob I am sorry for this question had an all nighter with c, inded code does change the value everytime

Comment: In actual program I have test data in int array, and Tree data type. I populate Tree with some data from the array, then I am trying to recursively free every value of the node and node in the tree and that fails. Is it because all the value pointers in the nodes are actually one memory chunk? should i then do something like memcopy of a value from the array into newly allocated memory space? @iharob

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr2 = (ptr);
```

This is just copying the *value* of the pointer. After this line, `ptr` and `ptr2` both point to the same allocated memory. Then,

```
free(ptr2);
free(ptr);
```

You're freeing the same allocation *twice*.

I'm not really sure what your code is supposed to be doing. You have two loops that are both overwriting the same block of memory. You also are, for some reason, writing 5 to the first `int` in that block.

Comment: And what about two different values for the same address?

Comment: Because you're writing data there in your first loop, printing it, then writing  a 5 there, printing it, and then your second loop is overwriting it. Again, `ptr` and `ptr2` point to the **same** memory. Anywhere you use `ptr2`, you might as well replace it with `ptr`.

Comment: Okay i asked wrong things, and Ii am sorryy, I've edited the question @Jonathon

Answer (score 1):

The two values in the same address are because of this

```
*ptr2 = 5
```

The **glibc** error is because of double `free(ptr)` and `free(ptr2)`.

Comment: First is for the question "why there are two different values for the same address".

Comment: My bad. Not wrong, but ambiguous which concern you were addressing.